# Stackblitz simple MatDialog example unable to find ComponentFactory

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, stackblitz

I am trying to set-up a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-9wmpkj) to ask a more complex question about an issue I am having with testing.

However, when setting up the basic example, while my basic test passes, clicking on the button to get the MatDialog to show throws an error that the ComponentFactory cannot be found. But I have added it to declarations and entryComponent in app.module.ts. What am I missing.?

p.s. The code itself works in my larger project, it is something about the way I am setting it up in Stackblitz that seems to be the issue.

p.p.s Based on Maihan's answer below, it got me thinking about the idea itself. Even though it builds and run, the idea complains about not being able to find the AddUserDialog component. But not sure why.

[image]

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { AddUserDialogComponent } from './AddUserDialogComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog){
};

openAddUserDialog(): void{
   const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

   dialogConfig.data = {
        employeeList:['foo', 'bar'],
        roles: ['fiz', 'faz']
    };

   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddUserDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((data) => {
   console.log('hello');
   });
 }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AddUserDialogComponent } from './AddUserDialogComponent';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatDialogModule, NoopAnimationsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, AddUserDialogComponent ],
  exports: [AppComponent, AddUserDialogComponent],
  entryComponents: [ AddUserDialogComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `app.component.ts` import from `@angular/material/dialog`:

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Instead of:

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
```

And inject it for root. This usually happens if you are using it in service or for lazy loaded modules.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AddUserDialogComponent implements OnInit {}
```

**You are loading `AddUserDialogComponent` dynamically, therefore, you have added in `app.module.ts > entryComponents`. You need to do the same in the test unit:**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [RouterTestingModule, MatDialogModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
    providers: [AddUserDialogComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent, AddUserDialogComponent]
  })
    .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: { entryComponents: [AddUserDialogComponent] }
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

Also, add `<my-app></my-app>` to your `index.html` for eliminating the following error in the console:

> The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

Comment: Thanks for the response. Good catch on <my-app> I was wondering why that was an issue. I do import from angular/material/dialog at the module level. I have now changed to angular/material/dialog on the component level as well. Unfortunately, I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Thank you again. It does not appear to be something with app itself. It is something about the test. If you click the first button on the right (the app) it works. If you click the button created by the test, the error is thrown.

Comment: BOOM! That was it. Thank you so much. I am pretty sure this is also going to solve what my higher level question was. :)